Capitalize first and last name in email address field
I am looking to standardize email addresses by formatting them as Firstname.Lastname@xyz.com in a Select statement.
I currently have records that have just lowercase letters for the first and last names, i.e. john.smith@xyz.com, whereas I need to standardize and make it as John.Smith@xyz.com.
All email addresses are formatted consistently as firstname.lastname@xyz.com, it's just the case that can be inconsistent in the names.
What string function will allow me to do this in SQL?

Hm… The (far?) more common pattern is all lower case e-mail addresses – if that's an option for you (your organisation), too, then it would be much more easily to realise as there's LOWER function ;)

Found this one – should be fine for you, too, just that you'd apply it only to the sub-string from the beginning up to the @ character.

a) why, because email addresses are typically case insensitive b) be careful because emails aren't always case insensititive

initcap() works with non-alphabetics as word boundaries. This would also work with middle initials as in john.a.smith@xyz.com:
replace(initcap(email), '@Xyz.Com', '@xyz.com')


That's a nice one. Would even fix case errors in the domain part ;)

I'd recommend a one-time update on the entire database table with and consecutively applying it to every individual INSERT or UPDATE for not having to repeat this work with every SELECT.

We can split the email addresses on the @ sign. For the first part, we use INITCAP to capitalize the first letter of both first name and last name.
The last part stays as it is and will be added to the first part.
We can use INSTR to find the position of the @ sign and split correctly.
So this query...
SELECT
  email,
  INITCAP(SUBSTR(email, 0, INSTR(email, '@')-1)) ||
  SUBSTR(email, INSTR(email, '@')) AS new_email
FROM yourtable;

...will produce for following sample data...
CREATE TABLE yourtable 
AS
SELECT 'John.Smith@xyz.com' AS email FROM dual
UNION ALL
SELECT 'maria.shaw@abc.com' FROM dual
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Pete.murhpy@def.com' FROM dual;

... following result:



EMAIL
NEW_EMAIL




John.Smith@xyz.com
John.Smith@xyz.com


maria.shaw@abc.com
Maria.Shaw@abc.com


Pete.murhpy@def.com
Pete.Murhpy@def.com



Sample fiddle here

This SQL query transforms email addresses in your table into the format Firstname.Lastname@xyz.com, Capitalizing only the first letter of the first and last names.
SELECT 
    CONCAT(UCASE(LEFT(email, 1)), 
           LOWER(SUBSTRING(email, 2, LOCATE('.', email) - 2)), 
           '.', 
           UCASE(LEFT(SUBSTRING(email, LOCATE('.', email) + 1, LOCATE('@', email) - LOCATE('.', email) - 1), 1)), 
           LOWER(SUBSTRING(email, LOCATE('.', email) + 2, LOCATE('@', email) - LOCATE('.', email) - 2)), 
           SUBSTRING(email, LOCATE('@', email))) AS Standardized_Email
FROM 
    yourtable;

The CONCAT function combines these bellow parts to generate the standardized email address.

UCASE(LEFT(email, 1)) will Uppercase the first letter of the first name.


LOWER(SUBSTRING(email, 2, LOCATE('.', email) - 2)) will Lowercase the rest of the first name.


'.' Adds a period between the first and last names.


UCASE(LEFT(SUBSTRING(email, LOCATE('.', email) + 1, LOCATE('@', email) - LOCATE('.', email) - 1), 1)) will Uppercases the first letter of the last name.


LOWER(SUBSTRING(email, LOCATE('.', email) + 2, LOCATE('@', email) - LOCATE('.', email) - 2)) will Lowercases the rest of the last name.


SUBSTRING(email, LOCATE('@', email)) will Keeps the domain part of the email address (i.e., @xyz.com).


You're reinventing the wheel, there's INITCAP already, see the other answers.
